# Medium of instruction - "is in English" or "was in English"

Tags: grammaticality

I have requested <strike>for</strike> a certificate from my college and received the same. In that certificate I am seeing one grammatical error. But I just want to confirm.

Here is the sentence in question:

> He has passed the course and the medium of instruction for the entire course of study is in English

Comment: If the medium of instruction for the entire course of study is ''still'' English, you shouldn't change that is with was.

Comment: Assuming that the course is still given in the form in which you took it, then *is* represents the enduring present.  Instruction was in English when you took it, it's taught that way now, and it's likely to be taught that way in the foreseeable future.

Comment: For the reasons @deadrat explains, either could, with equal justification, have been used. I would, however, point to a slight grammatical error in your OP. The verb *request* does not take a preposition, so we do not *request for* but simply *request* e.g *request a certificate*. Though if you had used *ask*, it would have been necessary to *ask for* a certificate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this example, "is in English" is correct because (presumably) the course is still available and being taught. If the course were only available once, and you happened to participate in that offering, then it would be in the past and you would say "was in English".